# Block is not-clickable in some areas during ::after animation

Tags: css

For some reason some areas of this block do not go to the specified image after a click (please try upper right part of the block). When I remove `animation: shine2 .6s ease;` part from `#examples .example-block:hover::after` the clicking works fine. It looks like this animation blocks the clicking in some parts of the block.

I'd appreciate help on this on :)

```css
#examples .example-block {
  border-radius: 0.813rem;
  background: #ebf3f7;
  box-shadow: 0 21px 40px -15px #a2c7da;
  transition: background .4s ease-out, opacity .4s ease-out, -webkit-filter .4s ease-out;
  transition: background .4s ease-out, filter .4s ease-out, opacity .4s ease-out;
  transition: background .4s ease-out, filter .4s ease-out, opacity .4s ease-out, -webkit-filter .4s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 283px;
  overflow: hidden; }
  
.text-center {
  text-align: center !important; }

@keyframes levitate-sml-grey {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px);
            transform: translate(0, 0px);
    box-shadow: 0 21px 40px -15px #a2c7da; }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4px);
            transform: translate(0, -4px);
    box-shadow: 0 25px 40px -15px #b4d2e1; }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px);
            transform: translate(0, 0px);
    box-shadow: 0 21px 40px -15px #a2c7da; } }

@keyframes shine2 {
  50% {
    left: -90%; }
  50% {
    left: 110%; } }
  
  #examples .example-block:hover {
    background: #15adfa;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #15adfa, #1cffff);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-animation: levitate-sml-grey 1.3s ease-in-out 1;
            animation: levitate-sml-grey 1.3s ease-in-out 1; }
            
    #examples .example-block:hover a {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
              transform: translateY(0%); }
              
  #examples .example-block:active {
    opacity: .8; }
    
  #examples .example-block::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -160%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #1cffff, rgba(28, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    -webkit-transform: skewX(125deg);
            transform: skewX(125deg);
    transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 1s ease-out; }
    
  #examples .example-block:hover::after {
    -webkit-animation: shine2 .6s ease;
            animation: shine2 .6s ease;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(225deg);
            transform: skewX(225deg); }
            
  #examples .example-block a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 500%;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
            
  #examples .example-block .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-out, -webkit-transform .4s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-out, transform .4s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-out, transform .4s ease-out, -webkit-transform .4s ease-out; }
    
  #examples .example-block:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg) scale(1.6);
            transform: rotate(7deg) scale(1.6); }
            
  #examples .example-block .svg {
    max-width: 41px;
    height: auto;
    top: 41%;
    position: relative; }
```

```html
              
<div id="examples" class="text-center">              
  <div class="example-block" data-aos="appear3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image" />
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="js-smartPhoto" data-caption="test" data-id="test" data-group="test"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30" class="svg" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jro8nLkv/5/ - Here everything works... I didn't edit anything. Maybe there is something else in your site, that prevents click... Maybe try to add z-index: 100500; ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME I slowed down the shine2 animation `animation: shine2 13.6s ease;` and it looks like when you click on where the gradient is then the click doesnt work. If you click outside the gradient, where it is transparent, then the click works.